Stuck on a black screen after picking an image when running iOS app
We are having a strange issue in our iOS app, we are running iOS app with ionic capacitor angular project. Here we are using the input element with type file.
<input type="file" accept="image/*" formControlName="profileImage" #profileImage (change)="profileImageUpload($event)" />
When we click on upload file, on a physical iOS device we get the option to capture the image from camera, we capture the image and click on Use Photo; after clicking that, we see a black screen from which we can not navigate to anywhere. If we select an image from the library, then it is working fine.
We tried the @capawesome/capacitor-file-picker plugin as well and used the element:
<ion-button expand="block" (click)="pickImages()" #profileImage>Pick Images</ion-button>
In this case as well, when we select the image and click on Use Photo, we see a black screen. One more thing we noticed is we are getting the image data in the click method (pickImages) but we are stuck on a black screen, so we are not able to see the selected image on our page.
We tried adding the file picker plugin but the problem persists.

so what debugging have you done?

When you used the @capawesome/capacitor-file-picker plugin, did you get a black screen when selecting an image from Photos? Or was the black screen issue only happening when capturing an image with the camera?

when we are using @capawesome/capacitor-file-picker  then we are using
<ion-button expand="block" (click)="pickImages()" #profileImage> and in this case we got the option to select images from gallery, when we pick the image the we get the black screen, even if we don't select the image and just hit cancel then also we get the black screen in iOS app.
